# How do I combine a search query and a sorting algorithm on the homepage of a Flask webapp?

Tags: python, sorting, flask, search, flask-sqlalchemy

I wrote this function in Flask:

```
@views.route("/index")
@login_required
def index():
    search = request.args.get("search")

    if search:
        posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(
            search) | Post.text.contains(search))

    else:
        posts = Post.query.all()

    for post in posts:
        date = post.date_created
        ups = len(post.likes)
        downs = len(post.dislikes)
        post.hot_score = hot(ups, downs, date)

        #print(post)
        #print(post.hot_score)
        
    sorted_posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda post: post.hot_score, reverse=True)
    
    return render_template("index.html", user=current_user, posts=sorted_posts)
```

It combines a simple search, with sorting using Reddit's hot algorithm.

Individually, these two functionalities work. They also work together as long as the search query only returns a single post. But for some reason, if the query returns more than one post I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'hot_score'`

I tried commenting out `sorted_posts` and simply returning `posts=posts`, while having a query that would return two posts. The code ran and the print statements gave me the two objects posts each with its hot_score.

For reference this is the Post table:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        "user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship("Comment", backref="post", passive_deletes=True)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='post', passive_deletes=True)
    dislikes = db.relationship('Dislike', backref='post', passive_deletes=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the conditional statement:

```
if search:
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.contains(
        search) | Post.text.contains(search)).all()

else:
    posts = Post.query.all()
```

The `.all()` method needs to be called on both queries otherwise query.filter won't return a list of objects and the `hot_score` attribute won't be added to post.